# Problema consulta Select en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy creando un formulario para registrar usuarios, funciona con campos normales, pero si quiero adicionar un `select` el formulario dice que no reconoce la variable.

> "Undefined variable: tipos_usuarios (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\crudgobernaciontres\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Esto es lo que tengo en el controlador:

https://paste.laravel.io/55570267-fc08-499a-bc98-d1a90b8b3663

Y esto lo que tengo en la vista.

https://paste.laravel.io/fed0355e-34f4-4890-bbe8-8215ce525d71

Tengo sospechas con este nuevo método que adicione en el controlador, Pero no estoy seguro..

```
public function lista()
   {
        $tipos_usuarios = \DB::table('tipos_usuarios')->select('id', 'usuarios_rol')->get();
        dd($tipos_usuarios);
        return view('auth.register')->with('tipos_usuarios', $tipos_usuarios);

    }
```

Comment: array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "Zl9sbau6v6ZG5Iw648AKnLirQj66wbBO4KtiDK4x"
  "name" => "ddd"
  "last_name" => "dddd"
  "username" => "dd"
  "email" => "dddd@gmail.com"
  "password" => "451905633"
  "password_confirmation" => "451905633"

Comment: No me envia el ultimo campo, que es tipos_usuarios... es como si este metodo lista() que configure no retornara nada, pero en realidad la consulta y el modelo estan bien.

Comment: Si lo agregaste a tu BD, así como a tu modelo y en tu controlador, puedes utilizar `$users = tipos_usuario::all();` te traerá todo lo que tenga el modelo

Comment: No... son dos tablas diferentes, el select viene de otra tabla, por eso separe un metodo diferente.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya resolvi el problema